# How to teach 5 year old to express emotion verbally?

Tags: pre-schooler, emotional-development

My 5-year-old son just cries when frustrated and throws his toy if angry. He is expressing his emotions only by actions, not by words. If he enjoys a movie he laughs in a loud tone. If he couldn't complete his snacks he cries and if his class teacher gives a star to his friend and not to him, he starts crying. Until he comes home, he cries without expressing his feelings to me; only his friend tells me what really happened. At home also if I am telling him to do some activity, if he is not interested he just shouts, he is not expressing it in words like "later I will do it". He is able to tell stories, he speaks normally only thing he is not expressing is his emotions with words. How do I teach him to express his emotions verbally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teach by example. Talk to him about his emotions, *as well as your own*.

"Are you sad that Mommy doesn't have time to play with you? I understand that, but she really needs to cook dinner now, she'll play with you later."

"It looks like you're angry that you can't have candy. It's OK to be angry, but shouting won't help. You know you can have only one candy every day, you'll get one tomorrow."

"I am really frustrated that I have to tell you for the third time to tidy your room. If I have to say it again I'll get angry and you won't get a bedtime story."

Children learn from observing others much better than from being told something.